# For Loop: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

I am trying to loop through some data returned returned from an API request which is structured as below:

```
[ { kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOption',
    saleTotal: 'USD107.70',
    id: 'fANabOjuLoDMb9zppwbeXL002',
    slice: [ [Object] ],
    pricing: [ [Object] ] },
  { kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOption',
    saleTotal: 'USD107.70',
    id: 'fANabOjuLoDMb9zppwbeXL003',
    slice: [ [Object] ],
    pricing: [ [Object] ] },
  { kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOption',
    saleTotal: 'USD107.70',
    id: 'fANabOjuLoDMb9zppwbeXL001',
    slice: [ [Object] ],
    pricing: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

However my for loop is giving me a type error which I'm struggling to debug. What am I missing?

```
  request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    //.log(response.trips.tripOption)
    let selects = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < response.trips.tripOption.length; i++) {
      if (response.trips.tripOption[i].selected) {
        selects++
      }
    }
    return selects
    console.log('hello' + ' ' + selects)

  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: tripOptions != tripOption

Comment: Ahhhhhh! I have updated that now. However it seems the code isn't making it to the `console.log(selects)`

Comment: It won't - `return selects` - exits the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo in `Line 6` in your snippet, writing `tripOptions` not `tripOption`.

Also, should `console.log()` before you `return selects`.

Comment: This is great thanks. The expected behaviour is each `select` being displayed. What I want to do is loop through the array and display each result. At the moment, `console.log` returns 0